# Gif image not animate after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some gif images on my website that I want to animate once you scroll to that part of the page. I have some JavaScript code that hides those gifs then shows them once you get to that part of the page. The issue I am having is that those gifs start animating before I scroll to that part of the page. Another issue I am having is that once I refresh the page the gifs will sometimes animate, but I would like them to animate each time the page gets refreshed.

Here is the link to my website: http://lam-parker.github.io/my_portfolio_website/

This isn't all of the gifs but here's is the portion of my html where my gifs are:

```
  <div class="row4">
        <h1 id="title3">Software Skills</h1>
           <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
               <img src="img/software-skills/photoshop.gif">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
               <img src="img/software-skills/indesign.gif">
           </div>
     </div>
```

Here is the .show()/.hide() JavaScript I added to the gifs section:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 70) {
    $('.row4').show("slow");
  } else {
    $('.row4').hide();
  }
});
```

I would appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only way to 'control' them would be to reassign the src attribute :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWvagO?editors=001)

```
img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  var current = $(this).scrollTop(),
  path = 'animated.gif',
  visible = $('img').css('opacity') != 0;

  if (current > 200) {
  if (!visible) $('img').attr('src', path).fadeTo(400,1);
  }
  else if (visible) $('img').fadeTo(0,0);
});
```

---

Update - by request some code that makes it possible to loop through *all* animated gifs :

[**Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LypgPR?editors=0010)

```
$(function() {

    var target = $('.anigif'),
    path = [], zenith, nadir, current,
    modern = window.requestAnimationFrame;

    target.each(function() {

        path.push(this.src);
    });

    $(window).on('load resize', storeDimensions).on('load scroll', function(e) {

        current = $(this).scrollTop();

        if (e.type == 'load') setTimeout(inMotion, 150);
        else inMotion();

    function inMotion() {

        if (modern) requestAnimationFrame(checkFade);
        else checkFade();
    }
    });

function storeDimensions() {

    clearTimeout(redraw);

    var redraw = setTimeout(function() {

        zenith = []; nadir = [];

        target.each(function() {

            var placement = $(this).offset().top;

            zenith.push(placement-$(window).height());
            nadir.push(placement+$(this).outerHeight());
        });
    }, 150);
}

function checkFade() {

    target.each(function(i) {

        var initiated = $(this).hasClass('active');

        if (current > zenith[i] && current < nadir[i]) {
        if (!initiated) $(this).attr('src', path[i]).addClass('active').fadeTo(500,1);
        }
        else if (initiated) $(this).removeClass('active').fadeTo(0,0);
    });
}
});
```

It will reinitiate them when they come into view (bottom *and* top) and fade them out when leaving the screen. All it needs is for the animated gifs to have a common class, assigned to the variable `target`. If the page contains only gifs and no other `<img>` tags you could even use `$('img')` and leave out the class. Looks like quite a bit of code but it has some debouncing and other optimisation.

B-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if I have several animated gifs. I can't replace your path = 'animated.gif', with my gif because it would change all of the images. I wanted to avoid created a different class and a separate function for each and every gif which is 12. Any suggestions?

Comment: Answer update for looping through all animated gifs, @Iparker.

Comment: Thank you so much for this update. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

You need to use CSS opacity 1 or 0 to show or hide your element. That is only way from "old-school".  Second thing is to use relative position and move out of screen. Also you can resize image from original size to 1x1px to original size but that is a bad way.

Comment: With this method, the gif would be playing in the background, so when it becomes visible it won't play from its beginning.